# TabHost cannot combine custom titles with other title features

Tags: java, android

I'm trying to add a title on one of my tab and got a java exception:
`android.util.AndroidRuntimeException: You cannot combine custom titles with other title features`

**The same code is working perfectly on Android v4.x but is not working on v2.2x**

- Can someone help me to solve this problem?

NB: I also use `ActionBarCompat` package provide by `Google`

Bellow my Java code:

```
public class MyNotepadActivity extends TabActivity {

    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT <= Build.VERSION_CODES.GINGERBREAD){
           requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE); 
           this.getWindow().setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN, WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN);
        }
        setContentView(R.layout.main);
        Resources res = getResources();
        TabHost tabHost = getTabHost();
        TabHost.TabSpec spec;

        Intent intent;
        intent = new Intent().setClass(this.getApplicationContext(),
        NotationActivity.class);
        spec = tabHost.newTabSpec("Notation").setIndicator("detail Note").setContent(intent);
        tabHost.addTab(spec);
    }
}
```

StackTrace:

```
08-29 08:39:39.329: W/dalvikvm(3063): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x400259f8)
08-29 08:39:39.349: E/AndroidRuntime(3063): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
08-29 08:39:39.349: E/AndroidRuntime(3063): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{org.biblio/org.biblio.MyNotepadActivity}: java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{org.biblio/org.biblio.MyNotepadActivity}: android.util.AndroidRuntimeException: You cannot combine custom titles with other title features
08-29 08:39:39.349: E/AndroidRuntime(3063): at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2787)
08-29 08:39:39.349: E/AndroidRuntime(3063): at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2803)
08-29 08:39:39.349: E/AndroidRuntime(3063): at android.app.ActivityThread.access$2300(ActivityThread.java:135)
08-29 08:39:39.349: E/AndroidRuntime(3063): at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:2136)
08-29 08:39:39.349: E/AndroidRuntime(3063): at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
08-29 08:39:39.349: E/AndroidRuntime(3063): at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:144)
08-29 08:39:39.349: E/AndroidRuntime(3063): at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4937)
08-29 08:39:39.349: E/AndroidRuntime(3063): at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
08-29 08:39:39.349: E/AndroidRuntime(3063): at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:521)
08-29 08:39:39.349: E/AndroidRuntime(3063): at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:858)
08-29 08:39:39.349: E/AndroidRuntime(3063): at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:616)
08-29 08:39:39.349: E/AndroidRuntime(3063): at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
08-29 08:39:39.349: E/AndroidRuntime(3063): Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{org.biblio/org.biblio.NotationActivity}: android.util.AndroidRuntimeException: You cannot combine custom titles with other title features
08-29 08:39:39.349: E/AndroidRuntime(3063): at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2787)
08-29 08:39:39.349: E/AndroidRuntime(3063): at android.app.ActivityThread.startActivityNow(ActivityThread.java:2627)
08-29 08:39:39.349: E/AndroidRuntime(3063): at android.app.LocalActivityManager.moveToState(LocalActivityManager.java:127)
08-29 08:39:39.349: E/AndroidRuntime(3063): at android.app.LocalActivityManager.startActivity(LocalActivityManager.java:339)
08-29 08:39:39.349: E/AndroidRuntime(3063): at android.widget.TabHost$IntentContentStrategy.getContentView(TabHost.java:651)
08-29 08:39:39.349: E/AndroidRuntime(3063): at android.widget.TabHost.setCurrentTab(TabHost.java:323)
08-29 08:39:39.349: E/AndroidRuntime(3063): at android.widget.TabHost.addTab(TabHost.java:213)
08-29 08:39:39.349: E/AndroidRuntime(3063): at org.biblio.MyBookActivity.onCreate(MyBookActivity.java:70)
08-29 08:39:39.349: E/AndroidRuntime(3063): at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1069)
08-29 08:39:39.349: E/AndroidRuntime(3063): at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2751)
08-29 08:39:39.349: E/AndroidRuntime(3063): ... 11 more
08-29 08:39:39.349: E/AndroidRuntime(3063): Caused by: android.util.AndroidRuntimeException: You cannot combine custom titles with other title features 
08-29 08:39:39.349: E/AndroidRuntime(3063): at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow.requestFeature(PhoneWindow.java:187)
 08-29 08:39:39.349: E/AndroidRuntime(3063): at android.app.Activity.requestWindowFeature(Activity.java:2760)
08-29 08:39:39.349: E/AndroidRuntime(3063): at org.biblio.ui.actionbarcompat.ActionBarHelperBase.onCreate(ActionBarHelperBase.java:64)
08-29 08:39:39.349: E/AndroidRuntime(3063): at org.biblio.ui.actionbarcompat.ActionBarActivity.onCreate(ActionBarActivity.java:53)
08-29 08:39:39.349: E/AndroidRuntime(3063): at org.biblio.SearchSudocActivity.onCreate(SearchSudocActivity.java:90)
08-29 08:39:39.349: E/AndroidRuntime(3063): at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1069)
08-29 08:39:39.349: E/AndroidRuntime(3063): at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2751)
08-29 08:39:39.349: E/AndroidRuntime(3063): ... 20 more
```

Answer (score 4):

If you have `Window.FEATURE_CUSTOM_TITLE` set, `setFeatureInt()` cannot be called again. A call to it will boil down to a [requestFeature()](https://github.com/android/platform_frameworks_policies_base/blob/master/phone/com/android/internal/policy/impl/PhoneWindow.java#L170) call in the Window implementation, that method tests for `FEATURE_CUSTOM_TITLE` and throws the Exception if it is set.

The problem is: The framework might request a feature on your behalf. I searched through the android code base and found only one case of this, the [generateLayout()](https://github.com/android/platform_frameworks_policies_base/blob/master/phone/com/android/internal/policy/impl/PhoneWindow.java#L2043) method, in my case it requested the `Window.FEATURE_ACTION_BAR` because I had the Holo theme enabled ... nasty thing to figure out, the work around is simple, [disabled the Holo theme](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/themes.html#SelectATheme)

Comment: I had inherited the holo theme in my custom theme.  Then when I tried to customize the title bar, the app was crashing.  Just removed the inheritance from holo and it worked fine.